# How do I echo out a sqli connect error within an innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to replace the html on button click with the mysql connect error message. The most simplified version of my code is shown below. I plan to have an if statement after I figure out why this doesn't work.

```
<?php
$test = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "table");
?>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<?php echo $test->connect_error?>';
}
</script>
```

The variable outputs if I define it like this

```
<?php
$test2='Anything';
?>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<?php echo $test2 ?>';
}
</script>
```

The connect_error displays if I just do this

```
<?php
$test = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "table");
echo $test->connect_error;
?>
```

But the first example returns a blank. Any ideas?

Comment: What does echo $test->connect_error; output? Is there a ' symbol there?